# Why can't I make a ToolStripMenuItem == True? How can I check to see if the menu item was clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public double[] pricearray = new double[] { 20.00, 50.00, 45.00, 40.00, 
    25.00, 80.00 };
    public double shipping = 0;
    public int quant = 0;
    public double bagquant = 0;
    public double bagprice = 0;
    public double shiptotal = 0;
    public double total = 0;
    private object eventhandler;

    public Form1()
```

Above I am declaring public variables

```
    private void fileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (clearToolStripMenuItem.Click == true)

        { 
        double shipping = 0;
        int quant = 0;
        double bagquant = 0;
        double bagprice = 0;
        double shiptotal = 0;
        double total = 0;
        }

        if (exitToolStripMenuItem.Click = true) 
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

It's a form for a online store. This is to clear any selections the user may have made.

Comment: Dont make it hard for someone to help you by posting a link to a picture of code. Paste it in the question.  And you should ask a clear question as well. *Working with...* is too broad.   Read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: If by "clear the selections" you are referring to the variables you are assigning to 0, do note that you are also [*declaring new variables*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/#specifying-types-in-variable-declarations) at the time you are assigning them to 0, and those variables go out of scope at the } that follows them.

Comment: `.Click` is typically an event, not a `bool`. You need to add the code to the respective event handlers, as you have with `fileToolStripMenuItem_Click`, so that it executes when the different `Click` events happens. Either that, or set some class-level `bool` variable in those other `Click` events, which you can check from the event code you've shown above.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the sender to a tool strip menu item, then check its name.

```
private void fileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Name == clearToolStripMenuItem.Name )
    { 
        double shipping = 0;
        int quant = 0;
        double bagquant = 0;
        double bagprice = 0;
        double shiptotal = 0;
        double total = 0;
        // I ASSUME YOU ARE DOING MORE THAN DECLARING LOCAL VARIABLES
    }
    else if (((ToolStripMenuItem)sender).Name == exitToolStripMenuItem.Name )
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```